# Subset of R consisting only of isolated points which is NOT closed?

Tags: general-topology

Hi I am in search of a subset of R consisting only of isolated points which is NOT closed.

Can you name any?

Comment: Yes, I can. Now for it to be not closed you need a sequence of points in your set with a limit that isn't in the set. I don't think you need any more...

Answer (score 2):

I think the set $A=\{1,1/2,1/3,...\}$ works.

Comment: (+1) In fact you can take any converging sequence (with infinitely many elements) and remove the limit.

Comment: Yours is the best possible answer, because it's the simplest. If you wanted to give a fancier example, you could use the midpoints of the open intervals removed in forming the Cantor set: $$\frac12,\ \frac16,\ \frac56,\ \frac1{18},\ \frac5{18},\ \frac{13}{18},\ \frac{17}{18},\ \frac1{54},\ \cdots$$